# Ant build error while running run target

Tags: java, xml, ant

I am using ant  1.9.0 to run my Java project.i have a bat file which has command ant clean compile run.the clean and compile is working but for the target run I am getting below error

```
 C:\Users\Susanta\MyMaven\MyMavenProject\build] on class org.apache.
 tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.XMLJUnitResultFormatter: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundErrorjunit/framework/TestListener
```

I am attaching the build.xml please let me know the issue in my build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
  <!DOCTYPE project [
]>

  <project name="MyMavenProject" default="usage" basedir=".">  

<!-- ========== Initialize Properties =================================== -->
<property environment="env"/>

<property name="ws.home" value="${basedir}"/>
<property name="ws.jars" value="${user.home}/.m2/repository/"/>
<property name="test.dest" value="${ws.home}/build"/>
<property name="test.src" value="${ws.home}/src"/>
<property name="test.reportsDir" value="${test.dest}/test_reports"/>




<path id="testcase.path">


    <pathelement location="${test.dest}"/>

    <fileset dir="${ws.jars}">
      <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>

  </path>




<target name="setClassPath" unless="test.classpath">
    <path id="classpath_jars">
        <fileset dir="${ws.jars}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
    </path>
    <pathconvert pathsep=":" 
        property="test.classpath" 
        refid="classpath_jars"/>
</target>

<target name="init" depends="setClassPath">
    <tstamp>
        <format property="start.time" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aa" />
    </tstamp>
    <condition property="ANT" 
        value="${env.ANT_HOME}/bin/ant.bat" 
        else="${env.ANT_HOME}/bin/ant">
                <os family="windows" />
    </condition>

</target>

<!-- all -->
<target name="all">
</target>

<!-- clean -->
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${test.dest}"/>
</target>

<!-- compile -->
<target name="compile" depends="init, clean" > 
    <delete includeemptydirs="true" quiet="true">
        <fileset dir="${test.dest}" includes="**/*"/>
    </delete>
    <echo message="making directory..."/>
    <mkdir dir="${test.dest}"/>
    <echo message="classpath------: ${test.classpath}"/>
    <echo message="compiling..."/>
    <javac 
        debug="true" 
        destdir="${test.dest}" 
        srcdir="${test.src}" 
        target="1.5" 
        classpath="${test.classpath}"
    >
    </javac>
  </target>

<!-- build -->
<target name="build" depends="init">
</target>




<target name="usage">
    <echo>
        ant run will execute the test
    </echo>
</target>

<path id="test.run">
        <fileset dir="${ws.jars}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
</path>



<target name="run" >  
    <delete includeemptydirs="true" quiet="true">
                <fileset dir="${test.reportsDir}" includes="**/*"/>
            </delete>
            <java jar="${ws.jars}" fork="true" spawn="true" />  
            <junit fork="yes" haltonfailure="no" printsummary="yes">
                <classpath refid="test.run" />  

              <!--  <classpath ="${test.classpath}"/> -->  
            <batchtest  todir="${test.reportsDir}" fork="true">  
            <fileset dir="${test.dest}">  

          <!--include name="tests/LoginTest.class" />
         <include name="tests/Parameterized_Test.class" />
         <include name="tests/TestApplication.class" /-->
          <include name="com/testing/GoogleTest.class" />
          <include name="com/testing/YahooTest.class" />





            </fileset>  
            </batchtest>    
                <formatter type="xml" />  
                <classpath refid="testcase.path" />  
        </junit>  
            <junitreport todir="${test.reportsDir}">    
                <fileset dir="${test.reportsDir}">  
                    <include name="TEST-*.xml" />  
                </fileset>  
                <report todir="${test.reportsDir}" />  
            </junitreport>  
        </target>
```

below is the error:

```
   C:\Users\Susanta\MyMaven\MyMavenProject\build] on class org.apache.
  tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.XMLJUnitResultFormatter: java.lang.NoClassDefF
 oundError: junit/framework/TestListener
 [exec]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 [exec]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
 [exec]     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
 [exec]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
 [exec]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
 [exec]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
 [exec]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
 [exec]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 [exec]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
 [exec]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
 [exec]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
 [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findBaseClass(AntClassLoader.java:1385)
 [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoaderjava:1064)
 [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.util.SplitClassLoader.loadClass(SplitClassLoader.java:58)
 [exec]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
 [exec]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 [exec]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
 [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.defineClassFromData(AntClassLoader.java:1128)
 [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.getClassFromStream(AntClassLoader.java:1299)
 [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1354)
 [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoaderjava:1315)
 [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.util.SplitClassLoader.loadClass(SplitClassLoader.java:52)
 [exec]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
 [exec]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 [exec]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
 [exec]     at 

   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.FormatterElement.createFormatter(FormatterElement.java:286)
 [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.logVmExit(JUnitTask.java:1653)
 [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.logVmCrash(JUnitTask.java:1617)
 [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.executeAsForked(JUnitTask.java:1099)
 [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.execute(JUnitTask.java:851)
 [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.executeOrQueue(JUnitTask.java:1899)
 [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.execute(JUnitTask.java:800)
 [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
 [exec]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [exec]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [exec]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
 [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
 [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
 [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
 [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)

 [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
 [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
 [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
 [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
 [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
 [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
 [exec] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: junit.framework.TestListener
 [exec]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
 [exec]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
 [exec]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 [exec]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
 [exec]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
 [exec]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
 [exec]     ... 48 more
 [exec]
 [exec] Total time: 7 seconds
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.773s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jul 07 03:01:39 IST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/18M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:
run (default) on project MyMavenProject: An Ant BuildException has occured: exec
 returned: 1
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<exec dir="C:\Users\Susanta\MyMaven\MyMavenProject" e
xecutable="C:\Users\Susanta\MyMaven\MyMavenProject\testrunner.bat" failonerror="
true">... @ 5:142 in C:\Users\Susanta\MyMaven\MyMavenProject\target\antrun\build
-runtheapp.xml
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal o
rg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (default) on project MyMaven
Project: An Ant BuildException has occured: exec returned: 1
around Ant part ...<exec dir="C:\Users\Susanta\MyMaven\MyMavenProject" executabl
e="C:\Users\Susanta\MyMaven\MyMavenProject\testrunner.bat" failonerror="true">..
. @ 5:142 in C:\Users\Susanta\MyMaven\MyMavenProject\target\antrun\build-runthea
pp.xml
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An Ant BuildException
  has occured: exec returned: 1
 around Ant part ...<exec dir="C:\Users\Susanta\MyMaven\MyMavenProject"    executable="C:\Users\Susanta\MyMaven\MyMavenProject\testrunner.bat" failonerror="true">..
. @ 5:142 in C:\Users\Susanta\MyMaven\MyMavenProject\target\antrun\build-runtheapp.xml
```

Comment: check the classpath when it runs test, `test.run` this variable

Comment: you need a junit 3 jar in your repository

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635481/running-pure-junit-4-tests-using-ant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this appears to be a ***known bug*** in `ANT 1.9.0`. see here: [Bamboo Ant Task fails when running junit task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481801/bamboo-ant-task-fails-when-running-junit-task/16490171#16490171)

read `comments #4, #5, #8 & #20` @ [THIS Link](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=36198#c4) for some help.

Comment: I am not getting the error after migrating to ANT 1.9.4

Answer (score 0):

The ANT manual describes how the [junit task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) requires an extra jar. This can be downloaded from Maven Central

- [List of junit versions](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22junit%22%20AND%20a%3A%22junit%22%20AND%20fc%3Ajunit.framework.TestListener)

And installed in the following directory:

- $HOME/.ant/lib

Personally I use an ANT plugin called [ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) to manage my build's dependencies, see:

- [Class not found with Ant, Ivy and JUnit - error in build.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15979391/class-not-found-with-ant-ivy-and-junit-error-in-build-xml/15982144#15982144)
- [Use Ant in netbeans to dynamically fetch latest versions of external libraries during build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079198/use-ant-in-netbeans-to-dynamically-fetch-latest-versions-of-external-libraries-d/17095611#17095611)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your error message:

```
C:\Users\Susanta\MyMaven\MyMavenProject\build] on class \ 
    org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.XMLJUnitResultFormatter: \
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError junit/framework/TestListener
```

Note the `NoClassDefFoundError` which means Ant couldn't find the class being referenced by one of your tasks. Was there a line number associated with this error? There should have been one pointing to the line that contains your `<junit/>` task. Even without that, you see that the class not found is `junit/framework/TestListener`.

The error messages in Java applications can be a bit intimidating because you see dozens, maybe hundreds of lines of stack trace. However, think of a Java program crash as a car accident. A car might have gone careening off the road, hit a telephone pole, bounced off that, hit another car, bounced off that, knocked over a fire hydrant, etc. You see a long trail of damage, but if you look at the first place where the accident occurred, you can usually see the problem (Look, there's a banana peel on the road!)

The same is true in Java error messages. The first line will usually tell you exactly what you need to know, and the exceptions are pretty easy to read. In this case, `NoClassDefFoundError` and it points to `junit` as the culprit. The next time you see something like this, you'll know what to look for.

---

As pointed out by [Mark O'Connor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24601210/368630), the jars needed for the JUnit task is not included with Ant. In fact, a lot of the defined tasks don't have the required jars to run those tasks, as you can see in [this table](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#librarydependencies) (and `<junit>` is the fourth item in that table).

In the Ant manual on [JUunit task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html), it states you can do the following:

> Note: You must have `junit.jar` available. You can do one of:
>
> 1. Put both `junit.jar` and `ant-junit.jar` in `ANT_HOME/lib`.
> 2. Do not put either in `ANT_HOME/lib`, and instead include their locations in your CLASSPATH environment variable.
> 3. Add both JARs to your classpath using `-lib`.
> 4. Specify the locations of both JARs using a `<classpath>` element in a `<taskdef>` in the build file.
> 5. Leave `ant-junit.jar` in its default location in `ANT_HOME/lib` but include `junit.jar` in the  passed to . (since Ant 1.7)

I personally prefer that last one. I usually place `junit.jar` in `${basedir}/antlib/junit`. This way, when someone checks out my project, they get `junit` with it.

In the [Ant FAQ](http://ant.apache.org/faq.html#delegating-classloader) it discusses some issues with `<junit>`.