# Configure Ant to use JUnit 4

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, junit

I googled for this, but I couldn't find any help.

I have a simple JUnit test class. Eclipse provides me with two options to run the test class in `Run as JUnit Test` in the Run configuration window, I see Test Runner `JUnit 3` or `JUnit 4`. This is working fine. My classes need to use JUnit4 runner.

Now I am trying to run this from the Ant JUnit task. However, it seems to me that Ant is using JUnit3 by default. I am not sure how to set it up to use JUnit4 test runner. I have only JUnit4 jar file in the classpath and I copied ant-junit4.jar from ant lib folder to my classpath. That shows     `[junit] Could not find the main class: org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.  Program will exit.` error.

I also tried JUnit4 Ant task. It shows there is no Junit4 ant task.
Help?

**Edit:**

I just left the ant-junit4.jar in the ant/lib folder and just removed `incudeantruntime` attribute in the junit task. It works, but again it uses Junit3.

**Edit**

I tried running from command like following:

```
 `java -classpath <myclasspath that has JUnit.jar as well> org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.my.TestClass`
```

and it works fine. How do I force ant Junit task to use this class `org.junit.runner.JUnitCore`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For others help,

Ant is using Junit3 test runner by default. No way I can specify the test runner in ant Junit task. I used workaround like from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7812246/668650) post.

Thanks @AlexanderMiles

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that you've got JUnit 4 inside of Ant lib folder. 
Please take a look at this question: [Running "pure" JUnit 4 tests using ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635481/running-pure-junit-4-tests-using-ant)

Comment: So just putting the junit.zip in the classpath is not enough? It should be in ant/lib folder?

Comment: I have ant-junit4.jar inside of lib folder of apache-ant-1.9.2, with the code from link it works just fine

Comment: I have it too. I have both ant-junit and ant-junit4. But its using Junit3 runner.

Comment: I did a small test. I remove `test` before the method in my test class. Now it says No tests found in my test class.

Answer (score 1):

From Ant manual for `junit` task-> http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html

> The <junit> task supports a nested <classpath> element that represents
>   a PATH like structure.
>
> As of Ant 1.7, this classpath may be used to refer to junit.jar as
>   well as your tests and the tested code.

This is where I would point to the right version of junit.jar file.

Use of dependency manager tool, such as Ivy or Maven (yes, you can use Maven just for dependencies) would be helpful here, so you don't have to commit the right version of binary junit jar file to your codebase.

Comment: I have right junit.jar in the classpath. But still ant uses old JUnit3 runner. I am using ant 1.9.x. Also, as I updated my post, I tried putting junit.jar in the ant lib folder as well. But did not work.

Comment: @KevinRave Do you `fork` your junit task?  This answer may be a clue -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/9825811/185722

Comment: Thanks for looking up for me, Alex. Yes, I already have that flag set to True. Still no luck.